# TypeOrm event.entity is undefined in subscriber when deleting using queryBuilder

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am removing object in my custom repository using this method:

```
removeById(id: number): Observable<DeleteResult> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(
      this.createQueryBuilder()
        .delete()
        .from(InspectionResult)
        .where('id = :inspectionResultId', { inspectionResultId: id })
        .execute()
    );
  }
```

My subscriber looks like this:

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class InspectionResultSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<InspectionResult> {

  listenTo() {
    return InspectionResult;
  }

  afterRemove(event: RemoveEvent<InspectionResult>) {
    console.log(event.entity);
  }
}
```

`afterRemove` is triggered, but I get undefined in `event.entity`. `event` object doesn't hold the info about removed entity at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please checkout similar discussion in [#2246](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2246) . In this case when you call delete you don't have any entities that orm can send you to subscriber. query builder just executes you DELETE * FROM table WHERE x. To fix this behaviour ORM needs to execute SELECT * FROM table WHERE x. It's not efficient of course =) **the entity is being passed to subscriber only when you call manager/repository's .remove method with entity passed.**